# memory allocation from heap in windows kernel mode

Tags: c++, windows, memory, kernel, driver

I'm working on Windows kernel mode driver development.

I believe the way we allocate dynamic memory on the heap in the **user space** is not applicable in the **kernel mode**.
I would like to know what is the **kernel mode** equivalent code for following piece of code(from user space).

```cpp
MsgAttriPtr = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, ulMessageAttributeBufSize); 
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, MsgAttriPtr);
```

In the code above I'm trying to allocate memory on the heap of size `ulMessageAttributeBufSize` and initialize it with zeros. Then I'm using `HeapFree()` to try and de-allocate/free the above memory.

Thanks,

Also please let me know what are the Windows native API headers to include for the functions we are going to use for kernel mode memory allocation on the heap.

Comment: Official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/managing-memory-for-drivers)?

Comment: It depends what kind of memory you need.  Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/allocating-system-space-memory

Comment: Thanks guys, i think we can use ExAllocatePool2( ) & ExFreePoolWithTag( ) in kernel mode to replicate/imitate user mode functions HeapAlloc( ) & HeapFree( ).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-exfreepoolwithtag   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-exallocatepool2